# Convert opencv::Mat to std::string gives std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a `cv::Mat` of size `2064x1544` and I want to save it as a `std::string`.
 My code is simple:

```
std::string image_string(image.begin<unsigned char>(), image.end<unsigned char>());
json["image"] = image_string;
```

As I wrote in the title of the question I hit this error:

```
std::bad_alloc
```

What's the problem?

Comment: What is `std::string{}.max_size()` on your platform?

Comment: There is no constructor for std::string which can that can transform 2 cv::Mat iterators to a std::string. Either write your own, or [check how to initialise strings](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)

Comment: @Roy2511 as long as it's an input iterator that dereferences (or implicitly converts to) `char` , a `std::string` is constructible from it.

Comment: @Timo the max is `9223372036854776000`

Comment: @Roy2511 I read this code from the Q&A of OpenCV

Comment: @Timo I see. Where's this in the documentation though?

Comment: @Timo https://answers.opencv.org/question/12/how-to-convert-cvmat-to-stdstring/

Comment: @Roy2511 [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using OpenCV's `cv::imencode` function over your attempt as it is more flexible and safer.

You can use this function to convert a `cv::Mat` to a `std::string`.
Note that you need to specify the image format. You might want to change ".png" to ".jpg" or whatever is supported by `cv::imencode(...)`.

```
std::string get_mat_as_string(const cv::Mat& cv_buffer_orig) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    if (!cv_buffer_orig.empty()) {
        try {
            std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;
            cv::imencode(".png", cv_buffer_orig, buffer);
            for (auto c : buffer) ss << c;
        } catch (std::exception& e) { std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl; }
    }
    return ss.str();
}
```

To retrieve the encoded cv::Mat inside the std::string you'd use

```cpp
   std::string buffer; // must contain encoded image from above function
   std::vector<byte> pic_data(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
   cv::Mat mat(pic_data, true);
   mat = cv::imdecode(mat, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
```

Now `mat` contains the original cv::Mat.

---

I originally wrote this (slightly edited) to transfer `cv::Mat`s over network, you can use it at your own discretion.

- ([Source, Original Encoder](https://gitlab.com/chris_nada/heliot_wildau/blob/master/klient_arm/src/fl_kamerastream.cpp))
- ([Source, Original Decoder](https://gitlab.com/chris_nada/heliot_wildau/blob/master/server/src/facereco/facereco.cpp))

Comment: Thanks. Why the output string is like this if I print it? `����JFIF��C     ���� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������?�&�rJ��������0���߽O>gﱴ66�v�^h17�n��Ͻ\����<�>�Cܿ9���������h�FF��g�|�����ᤐ� Q��{�{� x����t�"EEg����uE:5+��I J�.�l���
C��������V�`N�v;v������`�뎣=)�F�Ř������U�F�v`. It's encoded I know, but why it's not like `[210, 12, 32...]`

Comment: @User If you open a png or jpg file with a text editor it looks just the same.

Comment: Saving images in human readable form would be rather inefficient.